# Combine two CSVs in PHP by search CSV1 for item from CSV2?

Tags: php, csv, merge

I've written the following PHP script that will pull Base64 encoded pictures out of a database and write them to file. It also outputs a CSV, where each line has the Serial, Main Picture, Main Modified Date, Extra Pics, Extra  Pics Modified Date.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Edmonton');

$serverName = "database";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"CRM_MSCRM");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn === false )
    {
        echo "Unable to connect.\n\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
else
    {
        echo "Connected. Selecting trucks...\n\n";
    }

$tsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.Trader_Export_Simple";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false )
    {
        echo "Error executing query.\n\n";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

$csvData = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
        $count = 1;
        $mainpicsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.TruckImages WHERE Serial = '".$row[0]."' AND MainPic = 1";
        $mainpicstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $mainpicsql);
        while ($mainpicrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mainpicstmt))
            {
                $truck = $mainpicrow[1];
                $mainfilename = $truck ."-". $count . ".png";
                file_put_contents($mainfilename, base64_decode($mainpicrow[0]));
                $mainpicdate = $mainpicrow[3]->format("d/m/Y h:m:s");
                $mainfilename = "http://images.website/images/".$mainfilename;
                echo $mainpicdate."\n";
            }

        $picsql = "SELECT * FROM CRM_MSCRM.dbo.TruckImages WHERE Serial = '".$row[0]."' AND MainPic = 0";
        $picstmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $picsql);
        $extrapicsdate = "";
        $filenames = "";

        while ($picrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($picstmt))
            {
                $count++;
                $filename = $picrow[1] ."-". $count . ".png";
                file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($picrow[0]));
                $picdate = $picrow[3]->format("d/m/Y h:m:s");
                $filenames .= "http://images.website/images/".$filename.";";
                $extrapicsdate .= $picdate.";";
            }

        $filenames = rtrim($filenames, ";");
        $extrapicsdate = rtrim($extrapicsdate, ";");
        echo $filenames."\n";
        echo $extrapicsdate."\n";
        if ($truck != "") {
            $csvData[] = array($truck, $mainfilename, $mainpicdate, $filenames, $extrapicsdate);
        }

        if ($filenames != "")
            {
                $filenames = "";
            }        
        if ($extrapicsdate != "")
            {
                $extrapicsdate = "";
            }

        echo "Next truck...\n\n";
        $truck = "";
        $mainfilename = "";
        $mainpicdate = "";
    }
    $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($csvData as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    //print_r($csvData);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $picstmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
?>
```

I'd like to take the $truck from each line in this file, and search another CSV for the row containing that $truck, and append the columns from the matching row in this CSV to that one. Rinse and repeat for all lines in this CSV file

I just spent a while making this work after not using PHP for several years so my head's a little sore. Anyone want to point me in the right general direction on this part??
Thanks for the help!

Comment: looks like I'll need to use fgetcsv to read in the whole main CSV, search the resultant array for the serial, add the rows to the end, and iterate through until the second CSV has been exhausted

Comment: I've read in both CSV's to an array. now to match up rows and append as necessary